# Yii composite keys

Tags: php, yii

I have a table with a primary composite key a Room ID, Booking ID, a start date and end date.

When trying to build with CRUD there was a message saying that CRUD does not work with my composite key.

This line is in my Booking update method in Booking controller:

```
// Perform query of the BookingRoom table:
$bookingRoom = BookingRoom::model()->findAll();
```

This line is in my Booking update view:

```
<?php echo $bookingRoom->Id; ?>
```

The following message is displayed:

```
Error 500

Undefined variable: bookingRoom
```

render the update view

```
/**
     * Updates a particular model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be updated
     */
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model=$this->loadModel($id);

    // Perform query of BookingRoom table:
    $bookingRoom = BookingRoom::model()->findAll();
    //$models = BookingRoom::model()->findAll();        

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['Booking']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Booking'];
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->Id));
    }

    $this->render('update',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

Comment: Why are you fetching all bookingrooms in the update? And can you show the part where you render the update view?

Comment: I've tried using fetchByPK and array of columns as parameters, but I get a missing '(' message.

Comment: Creating a booking form

Comment: working now except it is asking for startDate.

The value for the column "startDate" is not supplied when querying the table "bookingRoom".

I don't want to specify start or end date.

Comment: $bookingRoom = BookingRoom::model()->findByPk(array('roomId' => 1, 'bookingId' => 1, 'startDate' => '20140619', 'endDate' => '20140620'));

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
$bookingRoom = BookingRoom::model()->findAll();
```

then

```
$this->render('update',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
```

then

```
<?php echo $bookingRoom->Id; ?>
```

You are not transmitting to the view the variable bookingRoom

Comment: this works now, but how do i fetch by PK? and without start and end date

Comment: working now except it is asking for startDate.

The value for the column "startDate" is not supplied when querying the table "bookingRoom".

I don't want to specify start or end date.

Comment: $bookingRoom = BookingRoom::model()->findByPk(array('roomId' => 1, 'bookingId' => 1, 'startDate' => '20140619', 'endDate' => '20140620'));

Comment: I saw you already have another question regarding that part. That is the right answer.